# Show top 1 by max column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, duplicates

I have a query which gets some information about specific jobs.

However, I am struggling to get the top record for each job (based on the latest 'LastRun' field).

Any help on how I can achieve this?

My query is:

```
SELECT 
job.Name,
CAST(CAST(hist.run_date AS CHAR(8))
+ ' ' 
+ STUFF(
STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(hist.run_time AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
, 3, 0, ':')
, 6, 0, ':')
AS DATETIME) AS LastRun,
CASE hist.run_status 
   WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed' 
   WHEN 1 THEN 'Success' 
   WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry' 
   WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled' 
   WHEN 4 THEN 'In progress' 
END AS Status,
CASE job.enabled
WHEN 0 THEN 'False' 
   WHEN 1 THEN 'True' 
END AS Enabled
FROM dbo.sysjobhistory hist
JOIN dbo.sysjobs_view job ON job.job_id=hist.job_id                    
WHERE job.[name] = '[Parallel] Copy DBOutboxMaster'  
OR job.[name] = '[Parallel] Copy filestore to PPE' 
OR job.[name] = '[Parallel] copyLogShippingForECW' 
OR job.[name] = '[Parallel] copyLogShippingForNLASQL'
GROUP BY job.name,hist.run_date,hist.run_time,hist.run_status,job.enabled
ORDER BY lastrun DESC
```

I currently get the results:

```
[Parallel] Copy DBOutboxMaster  2017-10-20 09:32:00.000 Success True
[Parallel] Copy filestore to PPE    2017-10-20 09:32:00.000 Success True
[Parallel] copyLogShippingForECW    2017-10-20 09:32:00.000 Success True
[Parallel] copyLogShippingForNLASQL 2017-10-20 09:31:11.000 Success True
[Parallel] Copy DBOutboxMaster  2017-10-20 09:31:00.000 Success True
```

As you can see there are duplicate fields for each job. I just want the top record for each job, so in total there should only be 4 results of the latest LastRun datetime

Comment: i dont understand where your duplicate jobs are

Comment: remove hist.run_time from group by, change it to max(or min?)(hist.run_time) in the select. WOuld that work?

Comment: @RyanGadsdon see the first record and last record in result. They are the same job

Comment: oh yeah sorry, it will be because you're grouping by the run time

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis this works but caused multiple records when there are different status fields, therefore I also put a max on this field aswell and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Have a sub-query that returns each job together with its LastRun. Join with that result.

Comment: note: a MAX() value might not align to the row containing the lastRun date (i.e. data could be inconsistent).

Comment: instead of string manipulation to arrive at a datetime, try this instead `dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,run_date),cast(run_time as datetime))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to George Menoutis, the answer to this is in the following query, by grouping the run date and the status fields:

```
SELECT 
job.Name,
MAX(CAST(CAST(hist.run_date AS CHAR(8))
+ ' ' 
+ STUFF(
STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(hist.run_time AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
, 3, 0, ':')
, 6, 0, ':')
AS DATETIME)) AS LastRun,
MAX(CASE hist.run_status 
   WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed' 
   WHEN 1 THEN 'Success' 
   WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry' 
   WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled' 
   WHEN 4 THEN 'In progress' 
END) AS STATUS,
CASE job.enabled
WHEN 0 THEN 'False' 
   WHEN 1 THEN 'True' 
END AS Enabled
FROM dbo.sysjobhistory hist
JOIN dbo.sysjobs_view job ON job.job_id=hist.job_id                    
WHERE job.[name] = '[Parallel] Copy DBOutboxMaster'  
OR job.[name] = '[Parallel] Copy filestore to PPE' 
OR job.[name] = '[Parallel] copyLogShippingForECW' 
OR job.[name] = '[Parallel] copyLogShippingForNLASQL'
GROUP BY job.name,job.enabled
ORDER BY lastrun DESC
```

Result:

```
[Parallel] Copy DBOutboxMaster  2017-10-20 09:43:00.000 Success True
[Parallel] Copy filestore to PPE    2017-10-20 09:43:00.000 Success True
[Parallel] copyLogShippingForECW    2017-10-20 09:32:00.000 Success True
[Parallel] copyLogShippingForNLASQL 2017-10-20 09:31:11.000 Success True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [TOP 1 WITH TIES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql) + [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM (
    SELECT  job.[Name],
            CAST(CAST(hist.run_date AS CHAR(8))
            + ' ' 
            + STUFF(
            STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(hist.run_time AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
            , 3, 0, ':')
            , 6, 0, ':')
            AS DATETIME) AS LastRun,
            CASE hist.run_status 
               WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed' 
               WHEN 1 THEN 'Success' 
               WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry' 
               WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled' 
               WHEN 4 THEN 'In progress' 
            END AS Status,
            CASE job.enabled
            WHEN 0 THEN 'False' 
               WHEN 1 THEN 'True' 
            END AS Enabled
    FROM dbo.sysjobhistory hist
    JOIN dbo.sysjobs_view job ON job.job_id=hist.job_id                    
    WHERE  job.[name] = '[Parallel] Copy DBOutboxMaster'  
        OR job.[name] = '[Parallel] Copy filestore to PPE' 
        OR job.[name] = '[Parallel] copyLogShippingForECW' 
        OR job.[name] = '[Parallel] copyLogShippingForNLASQL'
    GROUP BY job.name,hist.run_date,hist.run_time,hist.run_status,job.enabled
) as t
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY lastrun DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

CROSS APPLY is useful to "top(n) per row" requirements

```
SELECT
        job.Name
      , ca.LastRun
      , ca.Status
      , CASE job.enabled
                WHEN 0 THEN 'False'
                WHEN 1 THEN 'True'
        END AS Enabled
FROM dbo.sysjobs_view job 
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP(1)
                dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,run_date),cast(run_time as datetime)) AS LastRun
              , CASE hist.run_status
                        WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
                        WHEN 1 THEN 'Success'
                        WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
                        WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
                        WHEN 4 THEN 'In progress'
                END AS Status
        FROM  dbo.sysjobhistory hist
        ORDER BY dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,run_date),cast(run_time as datetime)) DESC
        WHERE hist.job_id = job.job_id
        ) AS ca
WHERE job.[name] = '[Parallel] Copy DBOutboxMaster'
OR job.[name] = '[Parallel] Copy filestore to PPE'
OR job.[name] = '[Parallel] copyLogShippingForECW'
OR job.[name] = '[Parallel] copyLogShippingForNLASQL'
ORDER BY ca.LastRun DESC
;
```

**EDIT**

To add seperate columns of types date & time together, a simple/fast method is to calculate the number of days from the zero date, then add that to the time, after casting the time value to datetime.

```
dateadd(day,  datediff(day,0,run_date)  ,cast(run_time as datetime))
```

Using number based date functions means you are not dependent on server settings to interpret strings into dates, and they are faster than conversion to/from strings.